# Let $G$ act on $A$, an abelian group. Let $B\le A$. Assume that $GB \subset B$. What is a natural way to define an action of $G$ on $A/B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Given $G$ a group acting on $A$ an abelian group. Let $B$ be subgroup of $A$. Assume that $GB \subset B$. What is a natural way to define an action of $G$ on $A/B$ ?

An obvious idea: for $aB \in A/B $, $G$ acts by sending $aB$ to $(ga)B$. However, to check if this is well-defined, one need to check if $(ga_1)B = (ga_2)B$ whenever $a_1B =a_2B$. So far, we have $a_2^{-1}a_1 \in B$, thus $g(a_2^{-1}a_1)\in B$.

But how can we show $(ga_2)^{-1}ga_1 \in B$? Is it true that $g(xy) = g(x)g(y)$ where $x,y \in A$?

Any correction or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $G$ is acting on a group $A$, then the elements of $G$ act as homomorphisms on $A$ (this is the definition of a group action on a group).  So, $g(xy)=g(x)g(y)$.  If you want to be more precise, a group action of a group on a group is a homomorphsim $\phi:G\rightarrow\operatorname{Aut}(A)$.

Comment: @Michael Burr Thank you,  does this definition of group acting on group come from a proof or it is just a natural definition ?

Comment: It's the definition.  You always map $G$ into the appropriate space of invertible maps on the target set.  Since $A$ is specified as a group, we assume that the group action respects the group structure of $A$ (otherwise, we would just have $G$ acting on $A$ as a set, not as a group).

Comment: Remark: For an abelian group $A$, we usually write the group operation *additvely*. Note that also $\Bbb Z$ acts naturally on $A$, and that altogether makes it a *module* over the group ring $\Bbb Z[G]$.